# How to compare strings that are storage sizes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a wrapper script in python to extend logical volumes. I am giving it a desired size, and it's able to get the exiting size.

```
existing_dict{} = {'root': '5.00g', 'opt': '10.00g', 'var': '20.00g'}
desired_dict{} = {'root': '10g', 'opt': '20g', 'var': '100%'}
```

How exactly do I compare the existing size value to the desired size value so I can take some action on it? So say the desired is same as existing then do nothing. If existing size is bigger than desired size then throw an error. If desired size is bigger than existing size, try to lvextend. Or, lastly, if the desired size is a percentage, then perform the lvextend with the percentage value.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - this code only provides a **`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`**

Comment: You would need to parse number / CI-unit and break it down to a base unit and use comparisons. Your code does neither - what did you try to solve it and where is your problem with your approach?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a fully working block of code yet, but your suggestion should work I believe. I am parsing the value of the key-value-pair and stripping out the float to be the size, and then the character as the unit. Of which then I can do comparison.

Comment: Please check if I answer below helps you @Eroji :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start with breaking down the string to kb or bytes, and then compare them
e.g. 5.0 G = 5x1024x1024 bytes

```
def convert_to_bytes(size):
    return size*1024*1024
existing_size = convert_to_bytes(size1)
required_size = convert_to_bytes(size2)
if existing_size < required_size:
    #resize
else:
   raise Exception()
```